# knockout data-bind issue on the Frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, review, file-upload, knockout

I have added file-uploader component in the review form. I have used below code to add browse button in the form.

```
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "#review-form": {
                        "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {},
                        "Magento_Review/js/validate-review": {},
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                        "components": {
               "uploader": {
                   "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader",
                   "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
                   "allowedExtensions": "csv",
                   "uploaderConfig": {
                        "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('{router}/{controller}/upload'); ?>"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
                    }
                }
</script>
```

If i put this code in the form tag then it is now working. If i put this code outside the form tag then it is visible. May be there is an issue related to the data-bind scope.

As in the review form, the form tag like below,

```
<form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAction()) ?>" class="question-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

As you can see, form has **data-bind="scope: 'review-form'"** and my file-uploader has **data-bind="scope: 'uploader'"**. So it may be an issue.

So, How can i fix this issue? Please help me. You help would be appreciated.